# Python + OpenCV, change brightness/darkness outside a sliding window?

Tags: python, opencv, brightness

I'm working with Python and OpenCV and I'm a newbie in both.
For my project, I need to move a sliding window over a picture; for each position of the window the area outside the window must be shown darker than the area inside the window.

This is the part of my code that takes care of the picture and window visualization (the valid positions for the sliding window are calculated somewhere else)

```
for (x, y, window) in valid_positions:        
    if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW:
       continue

    # Put here stuff to process the window content
    # i.e apply a classifier

    clone = image.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(clone, (x, y), (x + winW, y + winH), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Window", clone)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    time.sleep(0.025)
```

The window is created and it slides on the valid positions, so that part works well. But I have absolutely no idea on how to make the picture outside the window appear darker.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i forgot to add an important detail: my input images are always in black and white (not even greyscale, just black and white pixels). Maybe this makes it easier to alter the brightness/darkness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can preserve the content inside the window and lower the intensity of the entire image. Then replace the area inside the window with original content. That trick should work. This part of the code may look like

```
clone = image.copy()
windowArea = clone[y:y + winH, x:x + winW].copy()
clone = np.floor(clone * 0.5).astype('uint8') # 0.5 can be adjusted
clone[y:y + winH, x:x + winW] = windowArea
cv2.rectangle(clone, (x, y), (x + winW, y + winH), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```